# How to compute $K_0(S^1)$?

Tags: circles, k-theory

I am taking a course on K-theory and we have been asked to compute $K_0(S^1)$. Now I have a few conceptual problems: I see that $M_\infty(C(S_1))$ corresponds to "matrices of potentially infinite size with coeficients in $C(S^1)$", but how do I identify idempotents therein? My second question would probably be how to identify algebraically equivalent idempotents, but this question might be trivial depending on the answer of the first.
I want to compute this directly, so without using MV-sequence like arguments.

Comment: It sounds like this is a course on operator algebras? You can do this topologically but it depends on your background in algebraic topology; this amounts more or less to calculating $\pi_1(BU)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, it is a course on operator algebras. It was the first lecture, so we defined the group $K_0$ for unital associative algebras $A$. We did this by considering the Groethendieck group associated to the monoid of equivalence classes of idempotent elements in $M_\infty(A)$. I just don't see how to get from these abstract definitions to an explicit computation of $K_0$ for $A=C(S^1)$... I did take a course in algebraic topology a few semester ago. Could you please elaborate your comment a bit? thank you.